# Comparing time series data with different interval

Tags: time-series, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have time series data for one day (temperature) measured every 5 seconds and would like to increase the period between measurements and somehow calculate the level of error/similarity/correlation (I'm not sure which metric should be used)

There is a plot where blue line is data with period set to 5 seconds, and orange one with period set to 10 minutes. By looking at this plot one can assume that it's quite good aproximation but I don't know what metric should be used to describe it best.

[image]

Comment: There are many ways to compare the two series, and which is "best" will depend on your application. To compare the two curves in your graph, a simple first step would be to [linearly interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) the coarse series at the locations of the fine series. Then you can difference the two co-located series and proceed using the [residuals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/residuals).

Comment: @GeoMatt22 thanks. Can you help me with using `interp()` with date data? X axis in my case is time.

Comment: That is off topic for this site, but is probably answered already on [StackOverflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+interpolate+dates+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @GeoMatt22 ok, I managed to do it myself. Now I've got two plots - one with original data (10s interval) and interpolated one with 10 min interval. Could you elaborate more on the residuals that you mentioned?

Comment: My original comment was assuming you had the coarse series already. So as indicated there, interpolate the coarse (10 min) series to the fine resolution (10 s). Residuals are not critical, my main point was a simple way of reducing your problem to "comparing two identically sampled time series". This could be done using [standard metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics).

Comment: @GeoMatt22 thanks, now I have everything that I needed.

Comment: Great! Consider [documenting your solution in an answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).